# Trying to make a request with http in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make a class in Flutter that can send requests to an API and then store the response inside the class, however every time I send a request I get some sort of infinite request that end up in timing out. Here is my code:

- When the user press the button in the screen:

```
    onPressed: () async {
      print('Email: ${emailFieldController.text} and password: ${passwordFieldController.text}');

      await Api.sendRequest('POST', '/session', {
        "email": emailFieldController.text,
        "password": passwordFieldController.text
      });

      if (Api.content.containsKey("error")) {
        print("Error connectiong with API");
        print("The error was:" + Api.content["error"].toString());
      } else {
        if (Api.content["status"] == 200) {
          print("User find");
        } else {
          print("User not find");
        }
      }
    })
```

- The class that I built:

```
    import 'dart:convert';
    import 'package:http/http.dart';

    class Api {
      static final String baseURL = 'http://192.168.15.4/api/v1';
      static Map content;

      static Future<void> sendRequest(String method, String endpoint, [Map body, Map headers]) async {
        Response response;

        switch (method) {
          case 'GET':
            try {
              response = await get('$baseURL' + endpoint);
              Api.content = jsonDecode(response.body);
            } catch (e) {
              Api.content["error"] = e.toString();
            }

            break;
          case 'POST':
            try {
              response =
                  await post('$baseURL' + endpoint, body: body, headers: headers);
              Api.content = jsonDecode(response.body);
              print('Passando depois POST');
            } catch (e) {
              Api.content["error"] = e.toString();
            }

            break;
          case 'PUT':
            try {
              response =
                  await put('$baseURL' + endpoint, body: body, headers: headers);
              Api.content = jsonDecode(response.body);
            } catch (e) {
              Api.content["error"] = e.toString();
            }

            break;
          case 'DELETE':
            try {
              response = await delete('$baseURL' + endpoint, headers: headers);
              Api.content = jsonDecode(response.body);
            } catch (e) {
              Api.content["error"] = e.toString();
            }

            break;
        }
      }
    }
```

I also tried to alter the return type of the method, but got the same result.

Comment: Adding a little bit of info: The widget that receives tha information from the API is statefull and I conformed that the request does not reach my API I think Flutter might be "trapping" the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I discovered what was wrong, baseURL attribute was missing the port, so the request never found it's target. So in the and the baseURL value was: `http://192.168.15.4:3333/api/v1`